# If $ \forall A $ Logic Equivalent to $\forall B$ so $A$ is t-Equivalent to $B$

Tags: logic

True/False: If $ \forall A $  Logic Equivalent to $\forall B$ so $A$ is t-Equivalent to $B$.

$\forall A$ is a statement of the form: $\forall  x_1\forall  x_1...\forall  x_n A$ for all the free variables of $A$

Logic Equivalent Between X and Y: For every structure $M$ such that $M\models X$, also $M\models Y$.

Logic Equivalent Between X and Y: For every structure $M$ and assignment $v$ such that $M,v\models X$, also $M,v\models Y$.

I think I should refute it, but I just can't come up with the specific structure and assignments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the simple example which first occurred to me. Consider

> $\forall x\forall y\, x= y$

This is true only when the domain has a single member, and is thus logically equivalent to

> $\forall x\forall y (x= y \land \forall z(z = x))$

But plainly

> $x = y$

is not equivalent to

> $x= y \land \forall z(z = x)$.